# I want to change the format of a date in a Json to other

Tags: angularjs, json, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to change the format of a date that I get from a Json to other

this is the format that I'm getting
`"HoraInicio":"2016-08-26T03:00:00`"

and this iis the format of date that I want

```
/Date(1370284200000)\
```

the first two characters are the year, the third is the month plus one, the other one  don't matter.

I'm using this dates in a big Json to fill a kendo scheduler calendar, first I was using a XML to fill it, but de calendar don't even start, with the Json request works, but don't charge, I gess that the problem is for this date format.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. That format is not anything that is normal to javascript and in turn has to be parsed back to a proper date format. It's easy to do it though

Comment: Ok, what I've to do?

Comment: `'/Date( ' +(+new Date("2016-08-26T03:00:00")) + ')\'` will do what you are asking...but it really doesn't make any sense